# Is "trotted" okay in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Jay headed back to his office. Benji trotted over to him.

1. Is "trotted" perfectly okay here? (Benji half-runs to get to Jay before he enters his office) Or are there other and more common words I could use instead in this context?
2. I know it is used about horses. And when I look it up it also says running at a moderate pace with short steps. Why short steps? Will it sound comical if I used "trotted"?

Comment: Is Benji a dog?  Benji would be more common as a dog's name. There is a series of films about an orphaned puppy named Benji.

Answer (score 1):

The word "trotted" is used to liken Benji to a dog. The idea is that the narrator is trying to indicate that Benji is Jay's devoted little slave, and comes when he is called, like a dog.

It's ridicule.

Answer (score 0):

Trotted can also be used for humans. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trot) says

**(2) : a jogging gait of a human that falls between a walk and a run**

You could also try 'jogged over' - both work perfectly fine.

Take a look at Google's [NGRAM viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trotted%20over%2Cjogged%20over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrotted%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjogged%20over%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctrotted%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjogged%20over%3B%2Cc0) - the usage of both phrases is about the same.

As for why short steps, I guess it's just how normally jogging is done.